# Should I make white spaces between the lines?

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I don't know difference between two following codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The first line.

The second line.

The third line.
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The first line.



The second line.



The third line.
\end{document}
```

The second code has many white spaces between the lines.

Comment: With one or more newlines, LaTeX creates a new paragraph. There is no difference between two codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between these two code fragments. Adding white space to your code makes it more readable. LaTeX recognizes an empty line as a new paragraph. If you have more free lines they are ignored.

This is a big advantage of LaTeX and also prevents the setting of blank lines as a page break or spaces as tabs.